# Update command and SQLDataSource not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update, devexpress, sqldatasource

I fill my `<dx:ASPxTextBox>` (DevExpress Control) using the "select" command from the server side with the following code(this is an example there are 20 fields approx):`CustomerID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();`
which is working as expected!

However, i want to update my table using the `<asp:SqlDataSource>` control with  the same textboxes i use at the beggining as Control Parameters.When i give values to the textboxes in the .aspx page or like this `exampletextbox.Text = "test";` the update command works.  My conclusion is that i cannot update successfully my table because the textboxes get their values from an sqlcommand on the server side. Any ideas??? Am i doing something wrong?

Additional Code:

```
int customerUniqueID = 4;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString(); // connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE [UniqueID] = @UniqueID", con); // table name 
        com.Parameters.Add("@UniqueID", SqlDbType.Int);
        com.Parameters["@UniqueID"].Value = customerUniqueID;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Customers");

        CustomerID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();
        CustomerName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
        Details.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Details"].ToString();
```

SqlDataSource:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [CustomerName] = @CustomerName, [Details] = @Details WHERE [CustomerID] = 4">
```

Comment: <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" ControlID="CustomerName"  "></asp:ControlParameter>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="Details" Type="String" ControlID="Details" ></asp:ControlParameter>
Example: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="CustomerName" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1):

Problem found... I had to remove the "select" code from Page_Load.... -.-